# How to create a magic square in PHP?

Tags: php, math, numbers, puzzle, magic-square

I'd like to try my hand at creating a Magic Square in PHP (i.e. a grid of numbers that all add up to the same value), but I really don't know where to start. I know of the many methods that create magic square, such as starting "1" at a fixed position, then moving in a specific direction with each iteration. But that doesn't create a truly randomized Magic Square, which is what I'm aiming for.

I want to be able to generate an N-by-N Magic Square of N² numbers where each row and column adds up to N(N²+1)/2 (e.g. a 5x5 square where all rows/columns add up to 65 — the diagonals don't matter).

Can anybody provide a starting point? I don't want anybody to do the work for me, I just need to know how to start such a project?

I know of one generator, written in Java (http://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/how-to-make-a-magic-square.html) but the last Java experience I had was over 10 years ago before I quickly abandoned it. Therefore, I don't really understand what the code is actually doing. I did notice, however, that when you generate a new square, it shows the numbers 1-25 (for a 5x5 square), in order, before quickly generating a fresh randomized square.

Comment: Interesting link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html

Comment: Is this for homework? If so you should tag it thusly.

Comment: Why do people ask that for nearly every single question? If it was for homework, I would've labeled it as such. It's just for two hobbies of mine: puzzles and web development.

Comment: I second that. Too many people jump to conclusion that questions are for homework. It's one thing if the question is parroting a homework question ("Show that magic square has sum of N*(N^2+1)/2. Include reasoning."). yours is well stated.

Comment: @SiamakA.Motlagh: Please don't spam your links on every post in the thread. Also, the algorithm you're using is exactly the one that the OP says they *don't* want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has several algorithms for generating magic squares, such as the [siamese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_method), if you please. But as you say that's not a truly random magic square. It does reference a genetic algorithm, wonder whether you could find more details about that?

The method used by your referenced article is using some clever maths, [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). The actual algorithm isn't explained in the comments and I can't find any references to the details. I could imagine replicating the algorithm without understanding it, transcribing the existing Java - the core of the implementation is very few methods, arrays and arithmentic hardly any Java cleverness.

Comment: Actually, doing an "Anagram Magic Square" puzzle (which uses a 5x5 magic square), I stumbled across something interesting. The numbers 1-5 were on separate rows and columns, as were 6-10, 11-15, etc.

Then it hit me... since the diagonals won't matter (I basically want to make my own Magic Square Anagram puzzles) I could use the Siamese method, then swap around rows and columns randomly! I think it'll work... I just need to put it into practice.

Answer (score 3):

A simple Java program to do this, can be easily rewritten in any language:

```
/*
* Magic Square
*/

int order = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < order; col++) {
        int rowMatrix = (((order + 1) / 2 + row + col) % order);
        int colMatrix = (((order + 1) / 2 + row + order - col - 1) %
order) + 1;
        System.out.print(((rowMatrix * order) + colMatrix) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Algorithm:

1. Form a Square Matrix writing numbers 1 to nxn in sequence. Here n is
   the order of the Magic Square, say 5.

```
1        2       3       4       5  
6        7       8       9      10
11      12      13      14      15
16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25
```

2. We are trying to identify the final Matrix from the above. Form two
   matrices, one for identifying the row and another to identify the
   column.

```
4       5       1       2       3               3       2       1       5       4
5       1       2       3       4               4       3       2       1       5
1       2       3       4       5               5       4       3       2       1
2       3       4       5       1               1       5       4       3       2
3       4       5       1       2               2       1       5       4       3
```

You will see the middle column of the first Matrix starts with 1 and
are in sequence. Columns on either side can be filled by subtracting
and adding 1. The second Matrix is a mirror image.

3. Form the final Matrix by writing the number from initial Matrix in
   the corresponding row and column. For e.g 4, 3 (Step 2) = 18 (Step 1)

```
18      22       1       10      14
24       3       7       11      20
5        9      13       17      21
6       15      19       23       2
12      16      25        4       8
```

The above steps are applicable for any order of the Magic Square!

Comment: ?? please cite sources for your algorithm, or show why it works

Comment: This looks like the solution to my problem! It even has the bonus of having the diagonals add up to 65 as well. :D

Comment: Hi Jason, I figured out these steps myself to solve the magic square problem. I validated the solution by trying it out for magic squares of size that my pc could do. Not sure why it should work?

Comment: Check out the formula @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order

Comment: So I tried this out and the squares created by this method all look very similar. The restricted set of MSs returned by the above algorithm ensure the diagonals = 65. There's a wider set of MSs that can be returned if we ignore the diagonals (rows/cols only).

I'm looking at a puzzle called an Anagram Magic Square (sample here: http://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/Upload/PuzzleFiles/Sample/ang_p0508_samplepuz.pdf) and I'd like to generate magic squares as used by those puzzles (where the diagonals don't matter). There are solutions for these puzzles that can't be generated by the above algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could solve this with recursion?

In my opinion: Start somewhere with a random number e.g. down right corner,
than you start a function solve row, which calls itself until all rows are solved and a function solveField which calls itself until all fields in a row are placed correctly. (fills an array)

solceField places 1. a random variable if there are no restrictions 2. the missing number to complete a row (you should have a check that it doesnt place to high too fast => sum may not be greater than the remaining fields in a row)

if you get somewhere stuck you return false and go back one row and redo the row with a new random variable at its start.

Until everything returns true and you have a maqic square.